# power cycle a micro-controller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, raspberry-pi

Problem: 
Powercycle microcontroller when it stops transmitting a signal (heartbeat)

Question:
What device can I use to detect the signal and send an output signal? I am looking for something small as this devices function is very simplistic. (another microcontroller? timer? etc...)

Comment: What about the internal watchdog?

Comment: Your stated problem is not a problem, but a proposed workaround. A crutch. You should understand *why* it is stopping the transmission in the first place.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete power-cycle of a microcontroller and the entire surrounding circuit's low impedance voltage rail, as well, and not just a microcontroller or circuit "reset" pulse?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are correct this is a workaround but I need to install this since some crashes occur randomly (network fail, component crash, memory fail) and I am too far away to manually reboot

Comment: @TodorSimeonov is the internal watchdog 100% reliable? I have to make sure the system I put in place will never need intervention unless a cable is cut or unit unplugged

Comment: @SChand This is what I am talking about. There is no such a thing (almost) as "random crash". Every crash has a reason. You should take workarounds only if you are completely sure you can't control these reasons.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes I am sure I can't control these reasons and that is why I am seeking this solution (for now). I plan to continue finding ways to handle these crashes but I need a system in place right now to improve reliability.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a "watchdog circuit" or "watchdog timer".  They make cheap single ICs that can do this for you.  Your microcontroller may even already have one built-in!

Look [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-supervisors/691?k=watchdog).

[Here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/06/6a/b3/83/9a/c7/4f/22/CD00176077.pdf/files/CD00176077.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00176077.pdf) is a datasheet for a common one.

Comment: is it possible to do this watchdog reset when a script crashes?

Comment: Yes.  You would have the script toggle a pin on the watchdog timer.  When the script crashes the timer stops getting the input and triggers a reset.